# PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'D:/ftpchanger/temp/index.html'

Tags: python, ftp

Надо залить файл `index.html` на ftp сервер. Фрагмент кода:

```
fi = open('D:/ftpchanger/temp/index.html','rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR index.html', fi)
time.sleep(5)
fi.close
ftp.quit()
os.remove('D:/ftpchanger/temp/index.html')
```

По итогу выводит ошибку

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'D:/ftpchanger/temp/index.html'
```

Вроде бы понятно, что просто не закрыт файл,но при этом я закрываю его с помощью `fi.close`. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Уже решил, вероятно, но все же:

```
fi.close()
```

Comment: Да, так как это метод. А вы прописали его без оператора `( )` и получилось какое-то взятие атрибута.